Как можно ускорить компьтер?
Я пользователь персонального ПК уже как 3 года, внала после покупки компьютер показывал прекрасные результаты а вот после 1 года пользования все пошло насмарку, игры лагают, даже браузер иногда не запускаеться, слушал есть какие то бусты в биосе но боюсь их делать , я конечно могу но я не знаю как. Можете предложить ваш способ ускорения пк которым вы пользовались или о котором знаете.
ВОТ ДАННЫЕ ПК:
Intel Core i3 9100F,  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650

Сколько ОЗУ и сколько из них сейчас свободно? Тоже самое про диск. Системный диск, кстати, SSD хотя бы? Ну и в целом i3 - это не про комфорт в играх вообще.

Самое простое и надежное - переустановка ОС.

Попробуйте сначала сделать диагностику: найти причину,чтобы не тыкать пальцем в небо. Для этого надо скачать программу для диагностики например Aida64 и выложить отчет сюда, мы же не экстрасенсы тут собрались)
А за 3 года надо бы сделать профилактику продуть железо, смазать процик, остальное смотреть в программе диагностики.
Ну и банально система может быть забита мусором(программами работающие и забирающие ресурсы озу и проца) Также проверка антивирусом не мешает)
